# How to make a list non-clickable?

Tags: android, listview, clickable

i am using an AsyncTask  class to search a word, so i want to appear the word "searching" in the list
while proccess is executed

Okay, what I want to do is to have a non clickable list until search is completed, in order to ,if searching word is clicked nothing happens...

Which is the correct way to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you load, search and get data you can display a header view or/and a footer view in your `ListView`. Simply add these views before setting the adapter. When you search for a word, call [`setClickable(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) on the `ListView` and enable your header/footer view by, for example, calling [`addFooterView(mFooterView)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) to show your message.

Notice that you have to add the views before setting the adapter.

Example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
mFooterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
mListView.addFooterView(mFooterView);       
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

After this, feel free to call `addFooterView()` to show your message and call [`removeFooterView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#removeFooterView%28android.view.View%29) to hide your message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any direct solution (which there must be), but my way to do this would be:

**onPreExecute**:

1. Make your *ListView* `setEnabled(false)` so that its not click-able.
2. Set the visibility of your custom layout (containing searching message) to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in order to make it visible on top of your *ListView*. For that you need to combine your *ListView* and custom Layout in a `FrameLayout`.

**onPostExecute**:

- Simply reverse the process after you have altered *ListView* contents

By doing this way, you can show a transparent/translucent area covering your entire *ListView* with a message on top or center of it.

I've used this approach in one of my project and it looks pretty much nice :)

Comment: Thanks, but setClickable(boolean) was just what i needed :)

Comment: No probs. Either this way or that way, one must keep on coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `AsyncTask`, you can use a `ProgressDialog` with a message "searching" in `onPreExecute` method and dismiss it when you are done (in `onPostExecute`).

In this way, your ListView will also be disabled.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {     
    super.onPreExecute();       
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, message, "Please wait...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

   // set data for listview     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the notification to show that the query is executing ?

Because it can ensure the searching continues even you go out to the other apps.

The question you have asked implies the user of your apps waiting a long time to search a word and do nothing else, which is undesirable for the design of Apps for humans